# Why doesn't Rails pick up changes to my environment variables in AWS Elastic Beanstalk?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I've got an EC2 instance with Rails running and a few environment variables setup in AWS under Software Configuration. If I make a change to one of these variables, I find that the only way to get Rails to pick this up is to run an `eb deploy`.

I'm wondering if there is something I'm doing wrong. I've done some reading and some stack overflow posts indicate the issue might be **spring**, but I've only got spring running in development mode:

```
gem 'spring',        group: :development
```

When I connect to my EC2 instance and double check that spring is running, it is not. Is there some other type of caching that Rails might be doing?

I'm pretty new to this, so my apologies if my descriptions aren't super accurate.

Comment: When you say that Rails isn't picking up the new value, what do you mean? How are you determining that the new value isn't being used?

Changing a value in Software Configuration should end up doing two things, which you can verify by looking at `/var/log/eb-activity.log`:
1) Modifying `/etc/profile.d/eb_envvars.sh` with the new value
2) Restarting the app server

That should be sufficient for your app to pick up the new value, so there must be something else going on here.

Comment: Thanks Brian, in my Rails app, I have the following:

`class UserMailer < ApplicationMailer
  def welcome_email(user)
    @user = user
    @url = ENV['ADMIN_URL']
    
    mail(to: @user.email, subject: 'Welcome to my app.')
  end
end`

The ENV['ADMIN_URL'] is what is not being picked up unless I do an eb deploy.

Comment: Can you post what happens in `/var/log/eb-activity.log` after you update the value in Software Configuration?

Comment: Mine is also same problem. the variables that are stored under .env file are getting picked up during production on aws ubuntu server